# Cloud function have to be called twice before sending mail with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

When I'm trying to call my cloud function (which sends a mail with nodemailer) I have to call it once before it actually "activates" and afterwards it works normally until some time have passed and the same process is necessary.

On the first call I do not receive logs.

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    return res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: it could be due to cold starts, have u tried adding a return statement on the transporter method? that way you would avoid a timeout and do not let the function hanging on the next time it is invoked

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Isn't there already a return statement in transporter method?

Comment: there is a return statement that is trigger after the sendMail completes, in the meanwhile the function is hanging, you can promisify it, that would be my first step to debug it, I will give you a few recommendations on the answer

Comment: btw... with that implementation, arent u having cors issues? I assuming you do not cause you mentioned your function is executed the second time, but I'm just curious

Comment: No no issues beside the mentioned

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to promisify your response.

```
const sendMail = function(mailOptions, transporter) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(info);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Another way is to do something like

```
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(function(response) {
  return res.sendStatus(200);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.info(error);
})
```

I would put my coins on that.